# python3 - data type of input()

Tags: input, python-3.x

I need to assign a user-provided integer value to an object. My format is as follows:

```
object = input("Please enter an integer")
```

The following print tests...

```
print(type(object))
print(object)
```

...return `<class 'str'>` and '1'. Is there a way to set the data type of 'object' to the data type of the user's input value? IOW, such that if object=1, type(object)=int? I know I can set the data type of an input to int using the following:

```
object = int(input("Please enter an integer"))
```

In this case, if the user does not provide an int, the console throws a traceback error and the program crashes. I would prefer to test whether the object is in fact an int; if not, use my program to print an error statement and recursively throw the previous prompt.

Comment: Please don't use `object` as a variable name; it's a builtin name used to refer to the Python universal base class. (Plus, it's a terribly generic name to start with.)

Comment: It has a unique name in my actual code, but I wanted to simplify my question. Still, thanks for your feedback/insight!

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
 try:
  object = int(input("Please enter an integer"))
  break
 except ValueError:
  print("Invalid input.  Please try again")
print(type(object))
print(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always catch a "traceback error" and substitute your own error handling.

```
user_input = input("Please enter an integer")
try:
    user_number = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    print("You didn't enter an integer!")
```

Comment: Thanks for prodding me to read more carefully, t'is indeed a ValueError. No such thing as a traceback error! Whoops.